# Where can I grow magenta spreen lambsquarters?

Tags: planting, hardiness-zone

I just heard about the edible weed called magenta spreen lambsquarters, and was wondering where I can grow it for medicinal purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Does best in full or part sun, slightly acidic soil (though as a weed it can handle neutral or slightly basic with little issues). Zone is N/A as it's an annual but wait for temp to be >55F before taking outside.

Chenopodium giganteum has no medicinal purposes, but it's decently nutritious.